# Why do I get "logits and labels must have the same shape" error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the following piece of code, which is a **simplification** of my actual code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tensorflow as tf
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer #text to vector.
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, LSTM, SpatialDropout1D
from keras.models import Sequential

DATASIZE = 1000

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(1000, 120, input_length = DATASIZE))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.4))
model.add(LSTM(176, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

training = [[0 for x in range(10)] for x in range (DATASIZE)] #random value
label = [[1 for x in range(10)] for x in range (DATASIZE)]    #random value
model.fit(training, label, epochs = 5, batch_size=32, verbose = 'auto')
```

What I need:

My endgoal is to be able to check whether a given input vector (which is a numerical representation of data) is positive or negative, so it is a binary classification issue here. Here all the 1000 vectors are 10 digits long, but it could be waay longer or even much shorter, **length might vary throughout the dataset**.

When running this I get the following error:

```
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 2) vs (None, 10))
```

How do I have to structure my vectors in order to not get this error and actually **correctly** fit the model?

**EDIT:**
I could change the `model.add(Dense(2,activation='sigmoid'))` call to `model.add(Dense(10,activation='sigmoid'))`. But this doesn't make much sense, I think. As the first parameter of Dense is the actual number of output possibilities. In my case there are only 2 possibilities: positive or negative. So rnndomly changing this to 10, makes the program run, but doesn't make sense to me. And I am not even sure it is using my 1000 training vectors....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last layer `dense` has 2 neurons, while your dataset has 10 labels. So technically, the last layer must have same number of neurons as the number of classes in your dataset which is 10 in your case. Just replace 2 with 10 in your last `dense` layer.

Comment: Why did it have 10 labels? The input vector is 10 digits long and has only 1 resulting label, positive or negative

Comment: Try printing the shape of your label.

Comment: I understand, yhea my label data is incorrect. Does it change anything if I do this
    
    data = [[0 for x in range(10)] for x in range (1000)];
    labels = [0 for x in range (1000)];
    model.fit(data, labels, epochs = 5, batch_size=32, verbose = 'auto');

in stead of this:

data = [[0 for x in range(1)] for x in range (1000)];

Both seem to work, but I am not sure whether under the hood it changes anything

Comment: You have identified that the problem is in your labels, my job was to point a potential solution.